# crystal reports : not recognizing Null value in record select

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have the custom forumla in my record seletion formula editor in Crystal reports 8.5

> {_v_hardware.groupName} =
>   {?companyname} and
>   ({_v_hardware.DriveLetter} = "C" or 
>   isNull({_v_hardware.Driveletter})

I'm trying to list all records with a drive letter C or has a Null value and it currently lists all records with the drive letter C but not the ones with null.  Am I handling the null values incorrectly?  I have also tried setting the {_v_hardware.DriveLetter} = NULL and that does not work either.

I should add the report is talking to SQL Server. the records are reading NULL in the table.

Update:
If I use the query

> {_v_hardware.groupName} =
>   {?companyname} and
>   isNull({_v_hardware.Driveletter})

it will list the records with just the Null values in the DriveLetter field and the companyname

If I use the query

> {_v_hardware.groupName} =
>   {?companyname} and
>   {_v_hardware.DriveLetter} = "C"

this also lists all records with the driveletter "c"

thanks in advance

Solution by heather:

```
if IsNull({_v_hardware.Driveletter) then
  {_v_hardware.groupName} = {?companyname}
else 
 (if {_v_hardware.DriveLetter} = "C" then
  {_v_hardware.groupName} = {?companyname}
   )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen Crystal do funny things depending on the order you evaluate your fields.  Sometimes I've had to break field checks into blocks when a `NULL` value is possible:

```
if IsNull({_v_hardware.Driveletter) then
  {_v_hardware.groupName} = {?companyname}
else if {_v_hardware.DriveLetter} = "C" then
  {_v_hardware.groupName} = {?companyname}
else
  false;
```

Its ugly, but it may work if that is the case.

Comment: I just tried the if then and it gives me the same result.. weird

Comment: Strange.  Try my edit to see if that gives you different results.

Comment: Darn, I'm stumped.  I hope you can find a solution to this phill.

Comment: figured it out.. put the 'if {_v_hardware.DriveLetter} = "C" then
  {_v_hardware.groupName} = {?companyname}' in Parenthesis and it worked..  thanks!